# how to add attributes after finding master page controls on master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

i have some LIST controls in my master page to that list i want to add attributes such as href attribute from code behind of master page based on some criteria if he is admin or user etc.
i have tried

```
Control mycontrol=FindControl(v.Item1) ///v.Item1 im getting from database which is actual id of control in my aspx code
mycontrol.Attributes.Add("href","~/sales.aspx")/// this is not working
```

please help im new to asp.net

Answer (score 2):

Just use HTMLAnchor or HTML Control

```
           //Example 1
            HtmlAnchor ct = (HtmlAnchor)FindControl("CRM1");
            ct.Attributes.Add("href", "~/Test.aspx");

            //Example 2
            HtmlControl ct2 = (HtmlControl)Page.Master.FindControl("CRM2");
            ct2.Attributes.Add("href", "~/Test.aspx");
```

Just tested. Both worked for me in my Master page

Comment: Please mark the comment as answer if it helped you.